# searchForItemInArray in Java - Nested For Loop

Tags: java, nested-for-loop

Java says ''the type of the expression must be Array type but it resolved to Int"

I'm looking to do a nested For Loop for the solution, but any other more more elegant suggestions are also welcome.

```
public class ArraySearch {
    
    public static int searchForItemInArray(int needle, int[] haystack) throws Exception {
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= needle; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < haystack.length; j++) {
                if (needle[i] == haystack[j]) {
                            
                }
            }
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `needle` is an `int`. What do you expect `needle[i]` to resolve to?

Comment: He is searching for a needle in a haystack, he probably just needs to change `needle[i] == haystack[j]` to `needle == haystack[j]`.  `needle` shouldn't be an array at all, and you also do not need a nested loop

Comment: Also, I would suggest you read [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/lang3/find-elements-in-an-array/) for more elegant ways

Comment: I understand now. It was ```needle == haystack[j]``` as Nexevis said.

Comment: Nitzan - As common and frustrating with general internet examples, my situation is different so it doesn't help me. These examples use Strings (And String methods?) where as this method is checking Ints

Answer (score 1):

needle is an Int variable so isn't part of an array.

The answer to fix the IF statement was `needle == haystack[j]`

Comment: Note that the loop `for (int i = 0; i <= needle; i++) {` is also not necessary. Only the inner loop is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If searching for an item in an arrray is actually what you want, then you don't need a nested for loop.

If the needle is the item that you are searching for and the haystack is the array, you need to parse the array one time, using only one for loop and check at each step if the current item is equal to the searched element.

```
public static int searchForItemInArray(int needle, int[] haystack) {
    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        if (needle == haystack[i]) {
            // return the position of the item in the array.
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are searching index of the needle it that array. If it is true, than your code can be as follows:

```
 public static int searchForItemInArray(int needle, int[] haystack) throws Exception {
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= haystack.length; i++) {
        if (needle == haystack[j]) {
           return i;             
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thx! At what stage do I implement the Exception that was asked for. And under what circumstances?

Comment: @AndyO  If you are referring to the fact that the method declares it can throw Exception - nobody here knows why that is part of the declaration.  You wrote the code - why did you include it?

Comment: It was something in a learning exercise to implement the code for the method, I assume to think of a possible exception when searching for an needle in the haystack